# Android - MapView removes parent's background

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a custom LinearLayout class that I use to give a framed look to my views. When I want to add something to a frame, I add my views inside that custom LinearLayout.

Now my problem is, in one of my frames, I use MapView. And this MapView causes the frame's background to be erased/removed randomly. The background is usually gone for a second and then it comes back. Sometimes only a part of the background is removed, but usually all of it. In the first screenshot, the frame is as it should be. And in the second screenshot, it is the case that background is disappeared.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more code, and your menu is coded by you? or it's Android Action Bar ?

Comment: No I don't use Android Action Bar. Unfortunately I cannot add any code due to my client's privacy policies. I know it is hard say something without seeing some piece of code. I just wanted to know if anyone had something similar. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring your header to front by adding bringToFront();

More details : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()

Comment: My background is not just the header, there is also some kind of shadow behind the MapView. So, this didn't work me. Thank you.